# CFStringRef seems to hold on to NSString with no strong reference with just __bridge (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

In ARC, __bridge is supposed to imply just a cast with no ownership transfer. But the following code snippet does not crash:

```
    int i = 8;
    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"abc%d",i];
    Employee* e = [Employee newEmployee];
    CFStringRef cfStr = (__bridge CFStringRef)(str);
    str = nil;
    printf("%s\n",CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfStr, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman));
```

When I assign nil to str, the string should ideally be deallocated and the printf line should crash.

Comment: "should crash" - well, it doesn't **need to** crash. It may work even if the instance is deallocated.

Comment: The memory just hasn't been reused yet. If you turn on malloc scribble or guard, you'll get your crash.

Comment: Similar: [Why does my object still work after countless releases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646947/why-my-object-still-work-after-countless-of-release/6647237#6647237), [Sending a message to a deallocated object is working!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575819/objective-c-send-message-to-deallocated-object-is-working-why?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Josh's comment:
"The memory just hasn't been reused yet. If you turn on malloc scribble or guard, you'll get your crash."